How to swipe from left to right for SwipeButton widget in flutter integration test
I'm writing the flutter integration test & need to swipe a SwipeButton from left to right all the way to make payments.
Below is the app code for swipebutton
        builder: (context, state) {
          return SwipeButton(
            key: const ValueKey(WidgetKeys.swipeToPay),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(26),
            height: 52,
            activeTrackColor: AppColors.white100,
            inactiveTrackColor: AppColors.white100,
            activeThumbColor: AppColors.neutral10,
            inactiveThumbColor: AppColors.white100,
            thumbPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
            thumb: const Icon(
              Icons.keyboard_double_arrow_right_rounded,
              color: AppColors.neutral100,
            ),
            onSwipe: () => _handleSwipeToPay(context),
            child: Text(
              context.translate('swipe_to_pay_cta'),
              style: TextStyles.semiBoldRegular.copyWith(
                color: AppColors.neutral20,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },

Here is how the UI looks like

and i tried below ways to swipe it
      await tester.drag(find.byKey(const ValueKey(WidgetKeys.swipeToPay)),
          const Offset(10, 0));
      await tester.drag(find.byType(SwipeButton), const Offset(500, 0));
      await tester.dragFrom(
          tester
              .getTopLeft(find.byKey(const ValueKey(WidgetKeys.swipeToPay))),
          const Offset(100.0, 0));

Can anybody help on how to swipe from left to right in the integration test?

guys, it worked for me by just adding a key for the ICON that actually gets moved.! Like below mentioned and
thumb: const Icon(key: ValueKey(WidgetKeys.swipeToPay), Icons.keyboard_double_arrow_right_rounded,color: AppColors.neutral100,), and     await tester.drag(find.byKey(const ValueKey(WidgetKeys.swipeToPay)), const Offset(300, 0)); worked for me to drag to right side.!
